# How to convert RDD[Array[Any]] to DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark

I have RDD[Array[Any]] as follows,

```
1556273771,Mumbai,1189193,1189198,0.56,-1,India,Australia,1571215104,1571215166
8374749403,London,1189193,1189198,0,1,India,England,4567362933,9374749392
7439430283,Dubai,1189193,1189198,0.76,-1,Pakistan,Sri Lanka,1576615684,4749383749
```

I need to convert this to a data frame of 10 columns, but I am new to spark. Please let me know how to do this in the simplest way.

I am trying something similar to this code:

```
rdd_data.map{case Array(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j) => (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)}.toDF()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a dataframe, Spark needs to know the data type of each column. "Any" type is just a way of saying that you don't know the variable type. A possible solution is to cast each value to a specific type. This will of course fail if the specified cast is invalid.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
    Array(
        Array(1556273771L,"Mumbai",1189193,1189198 ,0.56,-1,"India",   "Australia",1571215104L,1571215166L),
        Array(8374749403L,"London",1189193,1189198 ,0   , 1,"India",   "England",  4567362933L,9374749392L),
        Array(7439430283L,"Dubai" ,1189193,1189198 ,0.76,-1,"Pakistan","Sri Lanka",1576615684L,4749383749L)
    ),1)
//rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Any]]

val rdd2 = rdd1.map(r => Row(
    r(0).toString.toLong, 
    r(1).toString, 
    r(2).toString.toInt, 
    r(3).toString.toInt, 
    r(4).toString.toDouble, 
    r(5).toString.toInt, 
    r(6).toString, 
    r(7).toString, 
    r(8).toString.toLong, 
    r(9).toString.toLong
))


val schema = StructType(
List(
    StructField("col0", LongType, false),
    StructField("col1", StringType, false),
    StructField("col2", IntegerType, false),
    StructField("col3", IntegerType, false),
    StructField("col4", DoubleType, false),
    StructField("col5", IntegerType, false),
    StructField("col6", StringType, false),
    StructField("col7", StringType, false),
    StructField("col8", LongType, false),
    StructField("col9", LongType, false)
  ) 
)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2, schema)

df.show
+----------+------+-------+-------+----+----+--------+---------+----------+----------+
|      col0|  col1|   col2|   col3|col4|col5|    col6|     col7|      col8|      col9|
+----------+------+-------+-------+----+----+--------+---------+----------+----------+
|1556273771|Mumbai|1189193|1189198|0.56|  -1|   India|Australia|1571215104|1571215166|
|8374749403|London|1189193|1189198| 0.0|   1|   India|  England|4567362933|9374749392|
|7439430283| Dubai|1189193|1189198|0.76|  -1|Pakistan|Sri Lanka|1576615684|4749383749|
+----------+------+-------+-------+----+----+--------+---------+----------+----------+

df.printSchema
root
 |-- col0: long (nullable = false)
 |-- col1: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col3: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col4: double (nullable = false)
 |-- col5: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col6: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col7: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col8: long (nullable = false)
 |-- col9: long (nullable = false)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This worked perfectly, and very easy to understand. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

As the other posts mention, a DataFrame requires explicit types for each column, so you can't use Any.  The easiest way I can think of would be to turn each row into a tuple of the right types then use implicit DF creation to convert to a DataFrame.  You were pretty close in your code, you just need to cast the elements to an acceptable type.

Basically `toDF` knows how to convert tuples (with accepted types) into a DF Row, and you can pass the column names into the `toDF` call.

For example:

```
val data = Array(1556273771, "Mumbai", 1189193, 1189198, 0.56, -1, "India,Australia", 1571215104, 1571215166)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(data))

val df = rdd.map {
    case Array(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) => (
        a.asInstanceOf[Int],
        b.asInstanceOf[String],
        c.asInstanceOf[Int],
        d.asInstanceOf[Int],
        e.toString.toDouble,
        f.asInstanceOf[Int],
        g.asInstanceOf[String],
        h.asInstanceOf[Int],
        i.asInstanceOf[Int]
    )
}.toDF("int1", "city", "int2", "int3", "float1", "int4", "country", "int5", "int6")

df.printSchema
df.show(100, false)


scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- int1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- int2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- int3: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- float1: double (nullable = false)
 |-- int4: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- int5: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- int6: integer (nullable = false)


scala> df.show(100, false)
+----------+------+-------+-------+------+----+---------------+----------+----------+
|int1      |city  |int2   |int3   |float1|int4|country        |int5      |int6      |
+----------+------+-------+-------+------+----+---------------+----------+----------+
|1556273771|Mumbai|1189193|1189198|0.56  |-1  |India,Australia|1571215104|1571215166|
+----------+------+-------+-------+------+----+---------------+----------+----------+
```

**Edit for 0 -> Double:**

As André pointed out, if you start off with 0 as an Any it will be a java Integer, not a scala Int, and therefore not castable to a scala Double.  Converting it to a string first lets you then convert it into a double as desired.

Comment: Note that in the column named "float1" the OP has the possible values of (0.56 , 0, 0.76). This approach will fail because you're trying to cast an Integer to Double. A quick fix is to change "e.asInstanceOf[Double]" to "e.toString.toDouble"

Comment: 0 (as an Int) can be cast to double:
`scala> 0.asInstanceOf[Double]`  --> `res1: Double = 0.0`

Comment: But you are not casting a 0 "as an Int" to double. You are casting a 0 "as an Any". Try this: `(0 : Any).asInstanceOf[Double]`

Comment: A more detailed explanation can be found here: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/1448

Comment: Ah, yes I see now.  Good catch.  I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try below approach, it's a bit tricky but without bothering with schema.
Map `Any` to `String` using `toDF()`, create `DataFrame` of arrays then create new columns by selecting each element from array column.

```
  val rdd: RDD[Array[Any]] = spark.range(5).rdd.map(s => Array(s,s+1,s%2))
  val size = rdd.first().length

  def splitCol(col: Column): Seq[(String, Column)] = {
    (for (i <- 0 to size - 1) yield ("_" + i, col(i)))
  }

  import spark.implicits._

  rdd.map(s=>s.map(s=>s.toString()))
    .toDF("x")
    .select(splitCol('x).map(_._2):_*)
    .toDF(splitCol('x).map(_._1):_*)
    .show()

+---+---+---+
| _0| _1| _2|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  0|
|  1|  2|  1|
|  2|  3|  0|
|  3|  4|  1|
|  4|  5|  0|
+---+---+---+
```